# GWT Cell Table add selectionCell based off object

Tags: java, gwt

I'm following the GWT showcase example for the Cell Table but can't get it to do quite what I want. I'm passing the cell table a list of members, and each member has an arraylist of numbers. I'd like to put that list of numbers in a selectionCell but as far as I can tell its not possible. the GWT example has the categories being queried separately and then put in the selectioncell while I would like the selectioncell to be populated by the object being passed to the table. Here's the relevant GWT code

```
final Category[] categories = ContactDatabase.get().queryCategories();
    List<String> categoryNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Category category : categories) {
      categoryNames.add(category.getDisplayName());
    }
    SelectionCell categoryCell = new SelectionCell(categoryNames);
    Column<ContactInfo, String> categoryColumn = new Column<ContactInfo, String>(
        categoryCell) {
      @Override
      public String getValue(ContactInfo object) {
        return object.getCategory().getDisplayName();
      }
    };
```

here is my attempt so far

```
List<String> lotNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
//this doesn't work, I can't call object.getLotNumbers();

        SelectionCell lotNumberCell = new SelectionCell(lotNumbers);
        Column<Member, String> lotNumberColumn = new Column<Member, String>(lotNumberCell) {
            @Override
            public String getValue(Member object) {
                return object.getLotNumbers().get(0);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

SelectionCell is not setup to dynamically render the contents, it uses a static list of Strings to render the drop down each time it's displayed. If you want to have a dynamic drop down you'll have to create a new cell type that implements `Cell<List<String>>` or some other type you can iterate over to generate the drop down.

Comment: Hi nwilde97 could you please elaborate more on implementing Cell<List<String>>

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of DynamicSelectionCell.

Use a single DynamicSelectionCell object and use the *addOption* method to add options for each row. Options are stored in a Map with the Key being the row number.

For each row *$i* in the table the options stored in the Map for key *$i* are rendered.

Works on DataGrid, CellTable.

***CODE***

```
public class DynamicSelectionCell extends AbstractInputCell<String, String> {

    public TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> optionsMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
        @Template("<option value=\"{0}\">{0}</option>")
        SafeHtml deselected(String option);

        @Template("<option value=\"{0}\" selected=\"selected\">{0}</option>")
        SafeHtml selected(String option);
    }

    private static Template template;

    private TreeMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> indexForOption = new TreeMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>>();

    /**
     * Construct a new {@link SelectionCell} with the specified options.
     *
     * @param options the options in the cell
     */
    public DynamicSelectionCell() {
        super("change");
        if (template == null) {
            template = GWT.create(Template.class);
        }
    }

    public void addOption(List<String> newOps, int key){
        optionsMap.put(key, newOps);
        HashMap<String, Integer> localIndexForOption = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        indexForOption.put(ind, localIndexForOption);
        refreshIndexes();
    }

    public void removeOption(int index){        
        optionsMap.remove(index);
        refreshIndexes();
    }

    private void refreshIndexes(){
        int ind=0;
        for (List<String> options : optionsMap.values()){
            HashMap<String, Integer> localIndexForOption = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            indexForOption.put(ind, localIndexForOption);
            int index = 0;
            for (String option : options) {
                localIndexForOption.put(option, index++);
            }
            ind++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
            NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
        String type = event.getType();
        if ("change".equals(type)) {
            Object key = context.getKey();
            SelectElement select = parent.getFirstChild().cast();
            String newValue = optionsMap.get(context.getIndex()).get(select.getSelectedIndex());
            setViewData(key, newValue);
            finishEditing(parent, newValue, key, valueUpdater);
            if (valueUpdater != null) {
                valueUpdater.update(newValue);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        // Get the view data.
        Object key = context.getKey();
        String viewData = getViewData(key);
        if (viewData != null && viewData.equals(value)) {
            clearViewData(key);
            viewData = null;
        }

        int selectedIndex = getSelectedIndex(viewData == null ? value : viewData, context.getIndex());
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<select tabindex=\"-1\">");
        int index = 0;
        try{
        for (String option : optionsMap.get(context.getIndex())) {
            if (index++ == selectedIndex) {
                sb.append(template.selected(option));
            } else {
                sb.append(template.deselected(option));
            }
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("</select>");
    }

    private int getSelectedIndex(String value, int ind) {
        Integer index = indexForOption.get(ind).get(value);
        if (index == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return index.intValue();
    }
}
```